# How do I loop until the user put the correct input on java?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I'm writing this program and I want to display the message "Invalid machine number, please enter again" when the user puts a number that is not between 1000 and 2000. I'm trying to loop until the user puts the correct input but I can't. When I enter a correct number after entering an invalid one, it still displays the error message.

```
System.out.println("Enter Vending Machine number(number 1000-2000):");

int vendMachNo = scan.nextInt();

while(vendMachNo <1000 || vendMachNo >2000)
{
    System.out.println("Invalid machine number, please enter again");

    int VendMachNo = scan.nextInt();
    {

    }
 // ...
```

Comment: You declared two variables : `int vendMachNo` and `int VendMachNo`. Note that Java is case sensitive in the variable name !

Answer (score 2):

You've not reusing the variable, but creating a new one in a loop. It's not used anywhere:

```
int VendMachNo = scan.nextInt();
```

instead, you should reassign the one, that is checked in `while` loop:

```
vendMachNo = scan.nextInt();
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the OP's problem.  And also, even if it did, you should not be answering typo questions.

Comment: The thing is, if your answer be correct, then the OP should be getting a different error message.  There should be a syntax error instead.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen are you speaking about the edited answer?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look,

```
    System.out.println("Enter Vending Machine number(number 1000-2000):");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int vendMachNo = scan.nextInt();
    while((vendMachNo < 1000 && vendMachNo > 2000)) {
        System.out.println("Invalid machine number, please enter again!");
        vendMachNo = scan.nextInt(); // reinitialize
    }
    System.out.println("Exiting!");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using 2 diferents variables VendMachNo and vendMachNo, java is key sensitive so you have a problem there.
Try this:

```java
System.out.println("Enter Vending Machine number(number 1000-2000):");
int VendMachNo = scan.nextInt();

while(VendMachNo <1000 || vendMachNo >2000)
{
    System.out.println("Invalid machine number, please enter again");
    VendMachNo = scan.nextInt();
}
```